# in Wear OS add a ShortTextComplicationData with Icon

Tags: android, kotlin, wear-os, android-wear-complication

I'm trying to create a complication for Wear OS and having problem trying to add the icons, I'm using `ShortTextComplicationData` which can be combine with an Icon, according to the documentation [Here](https://developer.android.com/design/ui/wear/guides/surfaces/complications).

here is the current code

```
private fun createComplicationData(text: String, contentDescription: String): ShortTextComplicationData {
val complicationData = ShortTextComplicationData.Builder(
    text = PlainComplicationText.Builder(text).build(),
    contentDescription = PlainComplicationText.Builder(contentDescription).build()
)
return complicationData.build()
```

}

this code works correctly but I have no option to add an image, ShortTextComplicationData says I need to use a MonochromaticImage.

I tried working with this line `complicationData.setMonochromaticImage(???).build())` but I don't have a MonochromaticImage to add or how to create it.

not sure if going in the right direction, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the following code

```
val icon = IconCompat.createWithResource(this.baseContext,R.drawable.ic_sense_white).toIcon(this.baseContext)
complicationData.setMonochromaticImage(MonochromaticImage.Builder(icon).build())
```

the `IconCompat` help create the Icon then i can pass this to the complication data.